# Beside concepts are there any other void_t replacements in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, void-t

Assuming I do not want to write a concept (or my compiler does not support them) and there is no matching type trait is there C++20 non void_t way to check if I can construct A with arguments B and C?

Note: this is a [toy example](https://godbolt.org/z/s36PMY), real question is is void_t still the best way beside concepts to check if something compiles in C++20.

```
    template <typename A, typename B, typename C,typename = void>
struct my_is_constructible : std::false_type {};
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct my_is_constructible <A, B,C,
    std::void_t<decltype(A(std::declval<B>(), std::declval<C>()))>>
    : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: This question is basically asking, "Did they add any language features to solve this problem, other than the language feature they added specifically to solve this problem?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the detected idiom, which is an abstraction over `void_t`. This is pretty much the closest you can get from concepts without them:

```
template <typename Default, typename AlwaysVoid, template<typename...> typename Op, typename... Args>
struct detector {
    using value_t = std::false_type;
    using type = Default;
};

template <typename Default, template<typename...> typename Op, typename... Args>
struct detector<Default, std::void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> {
    using value_t = std::true_type;
    using type = Op<Args...>;
};

template <template<typename...> typename Op, typename... Args>
using is_detected = typename detail::detection::detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::value_t;

template <template<typename...> typename Op, typename... Args>
constexpr auto is_detected_v = detail::detection::detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::value_t::value;

template <template<typename...> typename Op, typename... Args>
using detected_t = typename detail::detection::detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::type;

template <typename Default, template<typename...> typename Op, typename... Args>
using detected_or = typename detail::detection::detector<Default, void, Op, Args...>::type;
```

It can then be used like this:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
using my_is_constructible_expr = decltype(A(std::declval<B>(), std::declval<C>()));

// Trait type that has ::value
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
using my_is_constructible = is_detected<my_is_constructible_expr, A, B, C>;

// template variable, even closer to concepts
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
inline constexpr bool my_is_constructible_v = is_detected_v<my_is_constructible_expr, A, B, C>;
```

Comment: Ah yes, I read something about this many years ago, but could not remember the name... too bad it is not in C++20, but then again maybe it is for best since it forces users to use 1 solution.

Comment: Concepts are in C++20 and are way better than the detection idiom. They are faster to compile and supports overloading properly. I don't think adding detection idiom would have worth it.